# SERIAL obj in a matlab CLASS

Tags: matlab, oop, serial-port

I am new to Matlab OOP.
I attached a class, where i am trying to open a serial port. I am able to generate the SERIAL OBJ but the fopen function doesn't work. The status never turn to on.

```
classdef Channel

properties
    COM
    Baudrate
    SERIAL_obj

end

methods
    % Constructor
       function thisChannel=Channel(COM,Baudrate)
            if nargin==2
                thisChannel.COM=COM;
                thisChannel.Baudrate=Baudrate;
            end  
       end

    % Generate SERIAL OBJ
       function SERIAL_obj=get.SERIAL_obj(thisChannel)
           SERIAL_obj = serial(thisChannel.COM,'Baudrate',thisChannel.Baudrate);
       end

    % Connect to SERIAL OBJ
    function OPEN_SERIAL(thisChannel)
        fopen(thisChannel.SERIAL_obj);
        pause(0.2)
    end
```

Here is the script to generate the object:

```
 c=Channel('COM197',230400);
 OPEN_SERIAL(c)
```

Here is the result :

```
Serial Port Object : Serial-COM196

Communication Settings 
   Port:               COM196
   BaudRate:           230400
   Terminator:         'LF'

Communication State 
   Status:             closed
   RecordStatus:       off

Read/Write State  
   TransferStatus:     idle
   BytesAvailable:     0
   ValuesReceived:     0
   ValuesSent:         0
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to [value vs. handle class semantics](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/comparing-handle-and-value-classes.html). So either make it a handle class by inheriting from `handle`, or write the open method as:

```
% Connect to SERIAL OBJ
function thisChannel = OPEN_SERIAL(thisChannel)
    fopen(thisChannel.SERIAL_obj);
    pause(0.2)
end
```

and call it as:

```
c = Channel('COM197',230400);
c = OPEN_SERIAL(c);
```

(This is untested, I dont have any serial devices attacted to try it)

With that said, I dont see the point of the class you created, `serial` class already exposes these properties and much more..